# Unknown Display error fix

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, vga

I have a very interesting question. My video card is an nvidia gt 730 and it supports 3 monitors. One VGA, 1 DVI and 1 HDMI. I have 2 monitors and both VGA. Now my second monitor's VGA cable at my computer is plugged in with an DVI changer. And i keep having this Unknown display. Can somebody help me? [Display settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkusM.png)

Comment: First thought the monitor does not work with the adapter.

Comment: Yes its working and showing image but ubuntu wont recognize and i cant change resolution and it has now 1280x1024 and this monitor is 1366x768

Comment: Please update the question with this info with the edit command.

Comment: From the resolution you have given I am thinking this is quite an old monitor?

Comment: This is quite old graphics card,  launched on June 18th, 2014. This new OS may simply not understanding the monitor info. That is just a guess as you have not give an version info for the OS you are using.

Comment: Please provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need - eg. exact version of Ubuntu (and tag it so) - check via "lsb_release --all" as well as the output of "xrandr" run as your user in a terminal. Format the output to make it readable, and add it to your question. Also, search for similar questions for your distro, it is a fairly common issue. Go well.